# How can I import javascript function in angular2 template

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-slider

I need slider and I use AdminLTE in my project

```
<input type="text" value="" class="slider form-control"
       data-slider-min="-200" data-slider-max="200"
       data-slider-step="5"  data-slider-orientation="horizontal"
       data-slider-selection="before" data-slider-tooltip="show"
       data-slider-id="yellow">
```

to convert input to div , it needs

```
<!-- Ion Slider -->
<script src="../../plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap slider -->
<script src="../../plugins/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    /* BOOTSTRAP SLIDER */
    $('.slider').slider();
});
</script>
```

first 2 I imported in index.html und last function in my tamplate after input
it doesn't work
Where and how can I input this function? I did it in index.html but it doesn't work

Comment: what version of AngularJs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript you are trying to use is jQuery, if you are not using jQuery than that code will not work. You can tell it is jQuery because of the `$`.

If you are using jQuery in your AngularJs app than double check that

```
<script src="../../plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../plugins/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
```

are actually loading.

Here is a "plain vanilla" Javascript implementation you can use in place of the jQuery implementation if you are not using jQuery:

```
<script>
    function initSlider() {
       var sliderInputElem = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');
       sliderInputElem.slider();
    }
    window.onload = initSlider;
</script>
```

By the way should be able to change

```
<script src="../../plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../plugins/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/plugins/ionslider/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<script src="/plugins/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
```

if plugins folder is at the root of your app. I try to avoid up directory `../` for any resource, because the paths are more fragile (become broken links do to some code reorganization in the future).

Answer (score 0):

Angular compiler flushes out your JS code in the application.
To include any JS code, you need to include the definition **filename.d.ts** along with the JS and declare all the variables you are going to use in the JS code in filename.ts.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to cut you function from `index.html` and have to paste in the `constructor` of same HTML where you are going to use carousel.

let suppose you are using this in your `app.component.html` file

```
<input type="text" value="" class="slider form-control"
       data-slider-min="-200" data-slider-max="200"
       data-slider-step="5"  data-slider-orientation="horizontal"
       data-slider-selection="before" data-slider-tooltip="show"
       data-slider-id="yellow">
```

then you need to use this function in `app.component.ts` like this

```
declare var $: any;
@component({
....
})
export class AppComponent{
constructor(){
    /* BOOTSTRAP SLIDER */
    $('.slider').slider();
}
........
}
```